# Manufactured home light fixture junction box mountings

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a Clayton manufactured home.   We replaced the light fixtures in a number of rooms and now the bathroom light fixture as well as the box it is mounted to has fallen out of the ceiling.  We [image]have found that the box was basically held by the Sheetrock and per Clayton, that's the standard.  It's a clip style box that rests on the Sheetrock per the guy my husband spoke with.  I would think this should be mounted to something solid and not resting on something like that.  Can anyone direct me further on what to do or if that's just a bad standard?  I appreciate your help.  I am attaching pics.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the box with a braced box, something line [this one](http://www.westinghouselighting.com/lighting-accessories/ceiling-fan-accessories/ceiling-fan-support-braces-and-boxes/saf-t-brace,-4-teeth-with-locking-screw-with-1-1-2-inch-deep-box-0101000.aspx).

[image]

They're designed for the bar to slip up into the hole, and then expand to bite into the nearby structural members. Once the bar is securely in place, the box can be attached to it.

Comment: With a heavily textured ceiling such as your, you probably should consider this solution because there is less chance in causing more damage to the ceiling. It would be very difficult to make a repair to that ceiling that will match the existing one.

Comment: Awesome....much appreciated.  We will definitely try to find this product. :)